# How to set the correct reading-pont of the changing remote text file

Tags: java, file, inputstream, bufferedreader

First of all, I'm developing applications using java language

There is a changing file on a remote server.

I'm reading the changing file periodically.
(A changing file means that the content of the file is removed above and the bottom is added.)

for example,

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

[past]

test.txt => content : a b c d e

a minute later.........

[now]

test.txt => content : c d e f g i j

(I'm sorry I can't raise my image because my reputation is not over 10)

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

The past text file consists of a,b,c,d,e 5 lines.

Here I succeeded in reading and storing all the lines from a to e.

a minute later, the a,b line was deleted and the f,g,h,i,j lines were added.

I have already saved from a to e, so I want to read and store from f to j
(I want to save the line after the last line I saved)

The way I thought about it was to search with the last line I saved.

Search for e and read and save from after if e is matched.

However, the example is alphabetical and there are only lines that are not duplicated.

If there are duplicate values, the searching is useless.
(I don't know in advance how much text is erased and how much it is added)

Is there a way to share a good offset in this situation?